# C# Remove Substrings from String array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

So, I want to write the file names of a certain directory to a text file. For my program I only need the file names, not the full path. I already put them in an array like so:

```
 string[] charDir = Directory.GetFiles(SettingsInit.Default.GameDir + @"\stages", "*.def", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

The output of `Directory.GetFiles()` are the full paths, e.g.:

> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\mugen_1.1\stages\radicalHighway.def

How can I remove the path from each item, so that I only get the file name? I thought about iterating through each item, but I don't know how to achieve this properly. Since I'd always write `charDir[charDir.ToString().IndexOf(i)]` in the foreach loop, I'm not sure if it would work this way.

Comment: You could use `FileInfo.Name`

Comment: One possible way: `string[] charDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(SettingsInit.Default.GameDir,  "stages")).GetFiles("*.def").Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

System.IO.Path is a really nice namespace.  Try the [System.IO.Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) function to get only the file name.

I also really like System.IO.Path.Combine, great feature.

Comment: yes ! don't do things like `SettingsInit.Default.GameDir + @"\stages"` but use `Path.Combine()` instead.

Comment: You surely mean `Path.GetFileName()` (like you linked), not `Path.Combine`. And link only answers are discouraged on SO. Please add some explanation or a little code example.

Comment: I said I ALSO really like the other function.  As in, I also use that one a lot.